# Different predictions by adding useless nodes to graph in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, inheritance, keras, lstm, keras-layer

Suppose I customize `LSTMCell`, by following code

```py
class HRU_LSTMCell(LSTMCell):

    def call(self, inputs,  states, training=None):
        return super(HRU_LSTMCell, self).call(inputs, states=states, training=training)
```

The above code returns same answer as when `LSTMCell` is directly used. However, when I modify the above code as following

```py
class HRU_LSTMCell(LSTMCell):

    def call(self, inputs,  states, training=None):
        state_1 = states[0]
        state_2 = states[1]
        states = (state_1, state_2)
        return super(HRU_LSTMCell, self).call(inputs, states=states, training=training)
```

The above code is literally modifying nothing but the prediction that I get is slightly different than that of `LSTMCell`. Even if I copy and paste the exact code from `LSTMCell`'s `call` method, I get slightly different answer than when I directly use pure `LSTMCell`. Why do I get different answers even when I am modifying nothing?

Comment: Hi  Ather Cheema, Can you provide a minimum reproducible code? It would be much easier to give a sample code that runs on google colab (for example).